# REGEX - Input must have x unique digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I was wondering if anyone knows a way for regex to detect that there has been a minimum of x digits used.

For example if I put in a number 6 digit number of 111222 but my regex says there must be at least 3 unique numbers this would cause a valid fail.

but if I had 123456 that would pass because there is more than three unique digits used.

Something like (obviously it wont be like bellow.)

```
/^[0-9]{6}*3$/
```

---

non regex way

```js
var telcstart = $('#num').val(),
  telc1 = (telcstart.match(/1/g) || []).length,
  telc2 = (telcstart.match(/2/g) || []).length,
  telc3 = (telcstart.match(/3/g) || []).length,
  telc4 = (telcstart.match(/4/g) || []).length,
  telc5 = (telcstart.match(/5/g) || []).length,
  telc6 = (telcstart.match(/6/g) || []).length,
  telc7 = (telcstart.match(/7/g) || []).length,
  telc8 = (telcstart.match(/8/g) || []).length,
  telc9 = (telcstart.match(/9/g) || []).length,
  telc0 = (telcstart.match(/0/g) || []).length,
  totaltelc = "a:" + telc1 + " b:" + telc2 + " c:" + telc3 + " d:" + telc4 + "e:" + telc5 + " f:" + telc6 + " g:" + telc7 + " h:" + telc8 + " i:" + telc9 + " j:" + telc0,
  finaltelc = (totaltelc.match(/0/g) || []).length;

if (finaltelc <= 8) {
  alert('passed');
} else {
  alert('failed');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="num" value="123451212111">
```

Comment: regex is not the right tool for the job here: you don't care about the sequence of characters, you care about the unordered set. Do you really have to use a regex?

Comment: *Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.* — which language, JavaScript?

Comment: @kennytm Yes JS sorry

Comment: @Touffy I didn't think so I have another solution in JS but it was jsut to see if anyone knew if it was possible with regex out of curiosity.

Comment: All right. As an exercise, I suppose it's mildly fun. Does your input string have a maximum length?

Comment: @touffy Yeah lets go for 11 digits 0-9

Comment: What you're looking for is "x ***distinct*** digits" not "unique digits". When I hear "unique digit", I assume that the digit appears exactly once (e.g., `1` is unique in `123` but not unique in `1123`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?=.*(.)(?!$|.*\1))(?=.*(?!\1)(.)(?!$|.*\2))[0-9]+$
```

```js
function check(value) {
  var res = document.getElementById('result');
  if (/^(?=.*(.)(?!$|.*\1))(?=.*(?!\1)(.)(?!$|.*\2))[0-9]+$/.test(value)) {
    res.innerText = '✓ OK';
  } else {
    res.innerText = '✗ No match';
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Enter a number with ≥3 different digits</p>
<p><input type=text onkeyup='check(this.value)'> <span id=result></span></p>
```

Let's split it up:

```
^
(?=
    .*(.)       # Pick any character in the string as group 1
    (?!$|.*\1)  # Ensure this is not the last character, but is the last unique character
)
(?=
    .*(?!\1)(.) # Pick another character in the string as group 2
    (?!$|.*\2)  # Same condition as above 
)
[0-9]+
$
```

The first condition ensures there is a string like `??1??a`. The second condition ensures a string like `???2?b`, where `1` ≠ `a` and `2` ≠ `b` and `1` ≠ `2`. From this we can conclude there are at least 3 different characters.

---

This can be easily generalized to e.g. at least 8 different characters needed:

```
^
(?=.*(.)(?!$|.*\1))
(?=.*(?!\1)(.)(?!$|.*\2))
(?=.*(?!\1|\2)(.)(?!$|.*\3))
(?=.*(?!\1|\2|\3)(.)(?!$|.*\4))
(?=.*(?!\1|\2|\3|\4)(.)(?!$|.*\5))
(?=.*(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5)(.)(?!$|.*\6))
(?=.*(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)(.)(?!$|.*\7))
[0-9]+
$
```

Because JavaScript only support up to `\9`, you can't use this method to check more than 10 different characters. At this point you should really question whether regex is a right tool for this job though .

Comment: This does not work. "123456" and "123444" are both valid strings according to the question's criterion (at least 3 unique digits) and also have length 6, but are not matched by this regex. For reference:

https://regex101.com/r/zVH8gF/3

Comment: @PedroCastilho Amended answer. OP's question wants 6 character. It can be easily changed to accept any number of characters by changing the `{6}` to `+`. Isn't this obvious? 

Comment: @PedroCastilho Your regex101 link doesn't prove anything because you haven't turned on the `/m` flag.

Comment: @kennytm Indeed I did not. I am sorry for my lack of caution. 

I did not know about the \[digit] pattern (such as \1). That makes this doable, although it isn't really a computer-theoretical regular expression anymore, which invalidates my answer. I'll amend it.

Comment: @PedroCastilho The feature is called [back-reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html). Yeah this makes the "RegExp" no longer a true regular expression, and indeed some NFA-based regex engine like Google's `re2` [does not support it](https://github.com/google/re2/issues/101) for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

You actually *can* do this with a regex, but it'll be very ugly and near-incomprehensible.

Looking at just one case, we can write a regex for a string that contains 0, 1, and at least one number from 2 to 9:

`/^0(\d)*1(\d)*[2-9](\d)*$/`

For each possible pair of numbers, we would have to write a regex like this ad combine all of them using `|` so that we catch all cases.

There are 10*9 = 90 pairs of distinct digits, and for each group there are 2 permutations, totalling 180 groups.

So we would have to do:

`/(^0(\d)*1(\d)*[2-9](\d)*$/)|(^0(\d)*2(\d)*(1|[3-9])(\d)*$/)| ... /`

Continuing for all 180 groups. That would be a *gigantic* regex, and would probably take a very long while to compile.

You should do this validation with code instead of running a regex.

EDIT: Apparently, JavaScript regexes have some extended features which make this doable, namely reusing the value captured by a given group. refer to @kennytm's answerr.

Comment: You beat me to it. Yes, any finite language can be expressed in a regex, but in the instance of OP's problem, the regex would just be a list of every permutation.

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to see if there was a simple regex way out there I didn't think there was to be honest. this would be way to convoluted but will take it as answer. I have also posted my jQuery solution

Comment: However, it would *not* take long to run, only to compile. The compiled automaton would be huge, taking up a lot of memory, but regular expressions (without lookahead/behind) always have linear execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on negative lookaheads you can ensure a different digit matches three times:

```
(\d)\d*?((?!\1)\d)\d*?(?!\1|\2)\d+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SU40ka/4)

- `(?!\1)` negative lookahead to ensure next match is not same as captured group #1
- `(?!\1|\2)` negative lookahead to ensure next match is not same as captured group #1 and group #2

Comment: This does not do what the user who asked the question wants it to do. It matches "112233", which has no unique digits.

Comment: @PedroCastilho OP's title is inaccurate, they only want at least 3 different digits. Check the JavaScript snippet in the question.

Comment: @PedroCastilho: `112233` has 3 unique digits and that's why it correctly matches it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function uniqueDigit(str)
{
    var a = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        (new RegExp( i, 'g')).test(str) && a++;
    }
    return a
}
console.log(uniqueDigit('10122211100')) // in str
console.log(uniqueDigit(222111333888))  // in int
var a = 123456;
console.log(/^\d{6}$/.test(a) && uniqueDigit(a) > 2) // example
```